# Can player meeples enter the exact same grid space?

Tags: tokyo-metro

In **Tokyo Metro**, the player meeples each occupy a single grid space on the map. We had owever I can't find anywhere in the rules claiming that meeples *can't* enter the same location.

After some discussion at our table, we couldn't come up with a strong argument why we should assume they couldn't when it's unstated. The design of meeples nearly the same size as grid spaces *could* be meaningful, but it also fits with the general minimalism of the game. Blocking *could* be a strategic element, but it's not necessarily hugely relevant when station builds are much more about turn order and liquidity.

Effectively there are actually 3 separate movement questions here, sorted roughly from weakest to strongest restriction:

1. Can meeples end their movement in an occupied space?
2. Can meeples *pass through* an occupied space?
3. Can meeples ride trains that already have a player passenger?

Comment: If someone could make the Tokyo Metro tag, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been clarified by the designer Jordan Draper on the [BGG forum](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2100685/pawn-movement)

> players and trains can occupy the same space.

I think the old adage of rules applies.  IF it was a rule that only one piece was allowed per space then the rules should say that.  If that wasn't explicitly stated I would assume that to be the case.

Comment: I do generally agree with the basic rule adage, though it seemed that a lot of work had been put into minimizing the components and text, so it felt slightly more likely to have been excluded accidentally. Thanks for the find! My search skills must've been weaker than usual. ;)

Comment: Oh and the "reasoning" from the designer was quite funny: "In Tokyo, everyone and everything occupies the same space, anyone who has been there will testify to this"